# Upgrade SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

I have a test environment set up with the following:

- Virtual Machine (Hyper-V)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1(x64-bit)
- Windows SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition SP4 (x64-bit)(default instance name)

  - 1 Database with Merge Replication set up... 3 publications with 2 subscribers each.

We are testing the procedure for upgrading to SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition (sp1)...

I have downloaded the iso for 64bit SQL Server 2012 Dev. (sp1) from MSDN (full licensed copy) and have started going down the upgrade path. At one of the final stages, where it begins a check for different criteria, we run into a bizarre issue as outlined below:

```
Rule "Upgrade architecture mismatch" failed. The CPU architectures of upgrading feature(s) are different. To upgrade these features, Setup architecture must be the same as the features being installed.
```

Furthermore, in the upgrade log file, I found the following (more verbose) output:

```
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Init rule target object: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.BlockMixedArchitecture
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Rule 'BlockMixedArchitectureUpgrade' detection result: IsMixedArchitectureInstall= True 
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Evaluating rule        : BlockMixedArchitectureUpgrade
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Rule running on machine: REPLICATIONTEST
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Rule evaluation done   : Failed
(03) 2012-12-28 14:02:45 Slp: Rule evaluation message: The CPU architectures of upgrading feature(s) and this installation program are different. To upgrade these features, Setup architecture must be the same as the features being installed.
```

I have made sure that we are on an x64 system and not an ia64 and I see no reason why a mismatch would be occurring. Something to note: We cannot simply install SQL Server 2012, and reattach the databases to it as we have over 20 live databases (in production) with over 40 publications set up... this would be an absolute nightmare if we had to re-set up replication.

---

Here is the version info for the SQL Server 2005 setup:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (X64) 
Dec 10 2010 10:38:40 
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

9.00.5000.00 indicated SP4.

---

I will be calling Microsoft support about this tomorrow.

Comment: Can you verify the edition you downloaded? Is it possible you downloaded the Standard edition of SQL 2012, and not the Developer edition?

Comment: I mentioned it in my post but I did download SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition (x64) SP1.

Comment: Can you run "select @@version" on the current instance and post the entire output.

Comment: Yes, sorry... I should have done that... I will add it as an edit to the original post.

Comment: Sounds like to me you are trying to install SP1 for SQL Server 2012, not SQL Server 2012 with SP1 included.

Comment: Nope... It is a ~3.5gb ISO that is the full SQL Server 2012 Dev. Edition WITH SP1... If it were just the SP, the installer wouldn't have gotten me anywhere near this far...

Comment: The amount of MVP and MCMs responding to this is outstanding!  Looks like someone on the MSDN forums ran into the same issue:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/ac93670a-9892-4615-a4b2-728494a7b0b5

Comment: Ali, I agree! As to the linked answer, I saw that earlier and my heart sank! As stated above, we have over 40 publications... Each of our clients have 3 publications (say we have 43 publications, that makes 14 agencies.) Each agency might have upwards of 20 people subscribing... There is no way we can afford to uninstall/reinstall for this upgrade...

Comment: In the SQL Server Installation Center left panel -> Options.  Is the Processor Type set to x64?

Comment: Yes sir. I checked that on my second upgrade attempt.

Comment: Could either tools (SSMS etc) or SSIS have been installed separately to the main install as 32bit?

Comment: That's a good question... I don't think so, but I will look into it.

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith Please post your comment as an answer so I can award the bounty. The issue was that SSIS and SSAS were installed as 32bit... I removed these packages, upgraded and all is well!

Comment: It's making me wait 10 hrs. before I can award the bounty. I'll post it when it's available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could either tools (SSMS etc) or SSIS have been installed separately to the main install as 32bit?